# How to use custom stream manipulators to save data in class instance?

Tags: c++, stream, iomanip

I want to use my own manipulator like this:

```
person << name << "Peter" << age << 45 << country << "Canada";
```

In the function:

```
ostream& person<<(std::ostream &os)
```

I want to save the data Peter, 45 and country into a class.

How can I use a custom manipulator like this?

I have not found any information to this on the web.

Comment: So where's the manipulator in this? `name` could be an output stream and `age`/`country` two variables. Or worse, `name`s type overloads `<<` as a template and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please at least explain what that manipulator would do. Just saying 'I want this' with no context does not give readers anything to work with.

Comment: What are the manipulators supposed to do? What is `name`?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: So, `person` is an instance of some class, on which you want to implement streaming into, with those manipulators dictating what said streaming does... right? Why do you prefer this design over setting member variables or calling setter functions or any of the other ways that properties can be implemented? Have you tried looking at how standard streams/manipulators are implemented?

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, right. I heard its possible to use it like this and I would like to try this once. Its just for an example to get familiar with C++

Comment: @uneven_mark Then I got this wrong with the manipulators. But how can I access in the operate overload function the next value?

Comment: @uneven_mark Could you probably make a small code example for me? I think this would help me alot. Or send me a link to a tutorial because I dont find anything similar on the web. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following:

```
class person {
public:
    enum class field {
        name,
        country
    };
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string country;
    field field_selector;
public:
    person& operator<<(field f) {
        field_selector = f;
        return *this;
    }
    person& operator<<(std::string s) {
        if(field_selector == field::name)
            name = s;
        else if(field_selector == field::country)
            country = s;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Use like this:

```
person p;
p << person::field::name << "Peter" << person::field::country << "Canada";
```

`field_selector` saves the last field that you selected via the operator overload, the overload for `std::string` then chooses the correct field to store to. If you have fields with multiple types you need to define overloads for each and decide what to do if the selected field is wrong. You should also define a default value for `field_selector` (which I didn't).

All of this is unnecessarily complicated. If the fields were `public`, you could simply use aggregate initialization or set the members directly. If they are to be `private` you can write setters/modifier functions doing the assigning for each field.